# Matlab - Legend does not show different colors

Tags: matlab, colors, legend, lines

can anybody help me?I cant show the legend lines different colors.How can I do it?

```
a1 = 0;  b1 = 4;
a2 = 4;  b2 = 10;
a3 = 6;  b3 = 20;

x1=a1:.01:b1;
x2=a2:.01:b2;
x3=a3:.01:b3;

f1 = 1 ./ (b1 - a1);
f2 = 1 ./ (b2 - a2);
f3 = 1 ./ (b3 - a3);

plot(x1,f1,'r',x2,f2,'b',x3,f3,'y');
grid
xlabel('0 < x < 7 , 0.01 örnek aralığında') % x ekseni başlığı
ylabel('Üstel dağılımın olasılık yoğunluk fonksiyonu') % y ekseni başlığı
legend('s1','s2','s3')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are plotting a vector `x1`, `x2`, `x3` against a scalar `f1`, `f2`, `f3`. From the documentation for [`plot()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html):

> If one of X or Y is a scalar and the other is a vector, then the plot
>   function plots the vector as discrete points at the scalar value.

Each data point in your vector is plotted against the corresponding f value as a separate lineseries, giving you 2403 separate line series. In your legend call you add legend strings for the first 3 line series, which are all going to be red since the first 401 lineseries are red. If your desire is to plot a horizontal line you can create vectors from your `f` variables using [`repmat()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)

Using your example:

```
a1 = 0;  b1 = 4;
a2 = 4;  b2 = 10;
a3 = 6;  b3 = 20;

x1=a1:.01:b1;
x2=a2:.01:b2;
x3=a3:.01:b3;

f1 = repmat((1 ./ (b1 - a1)), size(x1));
f2 = repmat((1 ./ (b2 - a2)), size(x2));
f3 = repmat((1 ./ (b3 - a3)), size(x3));

plot(x1,f1,'r',x2,f2,'b',x3,f3,'y');
grid
xlabel('0 < x < 7 , 0.01 örnek aralığında') % x ekseni başlığı
ylabel('Üstel dağılımın olasılık yoğunluk fonksiyonu') % y ekseni başlığı
legend('s1','s2','s3')
```

[image: Plot]